# How to subtract the values ​entered in a column from a cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I'm trying to make a spreadsheet to control financial expenses. How to subtract from a cell the values ​​entered in a column in Google Spreadsheet?

**Example:**

[image]

[image]

The expected result was **1,500**, but the formula is subtracting only cell B2

How to subtract the values ​​entered in a column from a cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way is to sum the values in B:

```
=A2-SUM(B2:B)
```